# Moving a SharePoint sub-site up a level and making it the new top-level site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sub-site

Have a Sub-Site that's not being used.  However, there is a Sub-Site underneath it that is heavily used.  Now the site owner wants to make the Sub of the Sub a new Top level Sub-site.  Is it possible for someone who doesn't have site admin level permissions?  If not, then I will just submit it up the chain in my environment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the input and output operations mentioned by Mangler but this requires the permissions of the site admin .

Here is the guide source:

[Import and export: Stsadm operations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-2007-products-and-technologies/cc262465(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

And here are some tips you should note:

1.Make sure you have deployed the same features and customizations  to the destination site.

2.Before you import the sites, please create a new top site with the same site template with the site to be imported, and use this site path as the URL parameter in the IMPORTE command line.

Comment: Thanks.  I don’t have Site Admin, but will make sure I add some parts of all the answers into our internal ticketing systems

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is using the powershell export-spweb command on the sub site you wish to move, and then import it , using import-spweb, at the url of the new site collection.

Comment: From my experience this is best approach.

Answer (score 1):

With out using powershell, you can actually save the site as template, (it would be hard for sites with a lot of default features activated / deactivated)

On SharePoint admin, go to classic features then create the site from there, select the tempalate to 'select tempalte later',

When the site got created you will be prompted on what template you will use on that site, select the site template solution you uploaded then you're good to go.

Hope the concept shed some light! Happy Learning!